# Asterisk - Distribute incoming calls to 2 destinations (load-balancing)

Tags: load-balancing, asterisk, sip, voip

As i have never done load balancing so i am a bit stuck on this. I would like to know how can i distribute incoming calls from certain number to 2 destination.

So assuming there are 100 calls per hour coming on this extension:

```
exten => 01234567890,1,Answer
exten => 01234567890,n,Set(oqgroup=BM)
exten => 01234567890,n,Goto(csdigital,csdigital)
```

How i can distribute these calls on 50/50 basis. So 1st call goes to extension A 2nd call goes to extension B, 3rd goes to A 4th to B etc...

My custom conf where you can see two (example) numbers two which i would like to load balance the incoming calls:

```
[route]
exten => route,1,Answer
exten => route,n,GotoIf($["${oqgroup}" = "BM"]?bm,1)
exten => bm,1,Dial(SIP/0222333444@outbound,,ro)
exten => bm,1,Dial(SIP/0222333555@outbound,,ro)
```

Comment: I think you can set up a queue to handle calls like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function RAND for this.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Function_RAND

something like this

```
[route]
exten => route,1,Answer
exten => route,n,Set(my=${RAND(1,2)})
exten => route,n,GotoIf($["${my}" = "1"]?bm,1:bm1,1)
exten => bm,1,Dial(SIP/0222333444@outbound,,ro)
exten => bm1,1,Dial(SIP/0222333555@outbound,,ro)
```

Please check code, I didn't checked but you should understand logic.

If you don't want to have random(cause some times it might chose randomly to send next call to same extension as before), you can use global variables and create global variable and assign value to it 0. And check before call value of this variable and if it is 0 then route to extension 0222333444 and change value to 1. If global value is 1, then route to other extension and change value to 0 back.

Keep in mind that after asterisk restart global variables are reset to initial value.

Comment: The idea with the globals is actually quite good - I like it :)